# Fetch records from a dynamic table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am tying to fetch records from a table with dynamic prefix, such as following 
`M_table(id, username, password), N_table(id, username, password)`.

In Java with JDBC;

```
String query = "SET @pre='M_'; SET @tablename=concat(@pre, 'table'); @query=concat(\"SELECT password FROM  \", @tablename, \" WHERE username = 'test'); PREPARE stmt FROM @query; EXECUTE stmt";

con.execute();
```

I already appended `allowMultiQueries=true` to dbURL, then it can run multiple statements at one query. However, the last statement `EXECUTE stmt` is not executed on MySQL.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Thanks